# Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'colorbox' error in Jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have included the correct jquery, colorbox js files in jsp file. Colorbox created appended in body. But it's not triggered on button click event. The error when I click is:

> Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method
>   'colorbox'

I am using jquery.colorbox-min-1.6.3.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: wrong version of supportive jquery or jquery.colorbox-min-1.6.3.js is used